# How to query devices using metadata in GCP IOT Core?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iot

When I go to the IOT Core Registry page (on the GCP console) and select a device, I can edit it. There's a "Device metadata" section there, reading the following:

> You can set custom metadata, such as manufacturer, location, etc. for the device. These
> can be used to query devices in this registry. [Learn more](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/concepts/devices)

Where the documentation page shows nothing about querying devices using metadata.
Is this possible at all? What can be done using device metadata?

I am asking because I am looking for the following features with Azure IOT Hub has with device twin tags:

1. Ideally I would like to enrich messages the device sends (state, events) with corresponding metadata.
2. Querying for multiple devices based on a metadata field.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One first has to add device meta data, before one can query it:

- https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/devices#creating_a_device
- https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/devices#getting_device_details

---

One can query `gcloud iot devices`[`list (--registry=REGISTRY : --region=REGION)`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/iot/devices/list):

```
--filter="metadata.items.key['test_metadata'][value]='test_value'"
```

See [`gcloud topic filters`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/filters) for more information about filter expressions.

Or with format: `--format='value[](metadata.items.test_metadata)'`

Comment: Obviously, and I did. It's also to set metadata at device creation, or edit metadata of existed device. But how can I query for devices based on metadata fields?

Comment: Use [`describe`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/iot/devices/describe) with `--flatten` and/or `--format` Also see https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/concepts/devices#differences_between_device_metadata_configuration_and_state

Comment: Getting metadata of a specific device (with `describe`) is doable, but I cannot get `gcloud iot devices list` to work with `filter` of metadata. Looks like only a portion of devices fields are supported there.

Comment: Also, I believe that even if that's possible, filtering is done on the client side. My goal is to have it done from an IOT Core SDK.

Comment: Where does it say that this would be a client-side filter? eg `--filter="metadata.list(show="keys"):test_metadata"` show only list devices with that metadata key. `test_metadata` is not a good example key name anyway, because there's no real purpose.

Comment: Except it doesn't work. It doesn't list any devices: `WARNING: The following filter keys were not present in any resource : metadata.items.key.test_metadata.value`

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier if you implement this using client libraries. Using the suggestion of @MartinZeitler `list` your devices then perform `get` for each device and then do the checking on the metadata. See Python code below for the implementation:

```py
from google.cloud import iot_v1


def sample_list_devices(meta_key_name,meta_val_name):
    # Create a client
    client = iot_v1.DeviceManagerClient()

    project_id="your-project-id"
    location="asia-east1" #define your device location
    registry="your-registry-id"
    parent=f"projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}/registries/{registry}"


    # Initialize request argument(s)
    list_request = iot_v1.ListDevicesRequest(
        parent=parent,
    )

    # Make the request
    list_result = client.list_devices(request=list_request)

    # Handle the response
    for response in list_result:
        device=response.num_id

        get_request = iot_v1.GetDeviceRequest(
            name=f"{parent}/devices/{device}",
        )

        get_response = client.get_device(request=get_request)
        if get_response.metadata[meta_key_name]==meta_val_name:
            print(get_response)
            return get_response

#define metadata key and metadata value that you want to use for filtering
sample_list_devices(meta_key_name="test_key",meta_val_name="test_val")
```

Filtered response:

[image]

See device configuration:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to query metadata the way you want it.  [The doc](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/concepts/devices#differences_between_device_metadata_configuration_and_state) says the following about the server.

"Cloud IoT Core does not interpret or index device metadata."

As you are already aware as a client-side workaround to simulate a query search, we can list all the devices first and then filter the output by metadata.